# How can i get a Sharepoint Folder Id by path?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am getting sharepoint folders by using the graph api as follows

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedteams
```

This give me back Jon data with id, displayname etc.

I the call
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{folder-id}/drive/items/root/children/](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7Bfolder-id%7D/drive/items/root/children/)
This gives back Json with files and folders.

Is there a graph api call that can give me back the id by using the path , instead of the Id ?
So if my folder is called TestFolder/TestA/TestB , cani access the contents and deails of this folder by using something like

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/TestFolder/TestA/TestB/drive/items/root/children/

I have tried using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/" + path + "/" \
```

but that is for onedrive not the sharepoint folder group folders.